# Drop duplicates based on one specific value Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, where I'm trying to drop duplicates based on a subset but only for a specific value.

I have the following dataframe :

```
Date          Name        Task  Hours  

2019-09-26    John Smith  A     24
2019-09-26    Bruce Pitt  A     24
2019-09-27    John Smith  A     12
2019-09-27    John Smith  B     12
2019-09-28    Emma Garcia A     24
2019-09-28    Emma Garcia E     24
```

I would like to remove the duplicated rows based on `Date`, `Name` and `Hours` but only where `hours = 24`

I know how to remove duplicates, but I don't know how to add this specific condition value in this line :

```
df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['Date', 'Name','Hours'],keep='first', inplace=True)
```

Expected output :

```
Date          Name        Task  Hours  

2019-09-26    John Smith  A     24
2019-09-26    Bruce Pitt  A     24
2019-09-27    John Smith  A     12
2019-09-27    John Smith  B     12
2019-09-28    Emma Garcia A     24
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is `duplicated`

```
df[~(df.duplicated(['Date','Name','Hours']) & df.Hours.eq(24))]
Out[53]: 
         Date        Name Task  Hours
0  2019-09-26   JohnSmith    A     24
1  2019-09-26   BrucePitt    A     24
2  2019-09-27   JohnSmith    A     12
3  2019-09-27   JohnSmith    B     12
4  2019-09-28  EmmaGarcia    A     24
```